# Automate user input when program runs

Tags: python

Is there a way to auto select a user input option via task scheduler or within the script itself? I'm using a colleagues code and it would save some time if this could be achieved.

Example code below where one of these options needs to be selected.

```
while True:
    choose_report = input(""" Please select the Report type

    1) Weekly
    2) Monthly
    3) Yearly
    4) Exit\n

    Review type:> """)
```

I've tried `argv` but that changes the variables of the script, which is what I could do but I was wondering if there is a quicker way without editing the script variables.

Comment: If you always want to select the same value, you can override the input call on the script with the wanted value, e.g. "3" for "Yearly" option.

Comment: you can place it in a [functon argument](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function-argument) that has a default value of `1` for instance

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a couple of different ways:

1. Pipe user inputs from a file through stdin.  For example: `my_script.py < inputs.txt`.  This will work without needing to change the original script, but is a bit less clear and more fragile if you ever want to change the behavior of the script in the future.
2. Refactor the script to use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), and don't ask for interactive input when running from the task scheduler.  Then you can specify all of the choices as script arguments, e.g. `my_script.py --report-type=monthly`.  This will take more work up front, but makes the script very easy to change in the future.